# Do hash functions/checksums without the diffusion property exist?

Tags: algorithm, hash

From Wikipedia:

> Diffusion means that if we change a single bit of the plaintext, then (statistically) half of the bits in the ciphertext should change, and similarly, if we change one bit of the ciphertext, then approximately one half of the plaintext bits should change.[2] Since a bit can have only two states, when they are all re-evaluated and changed from one seemingly random position to another, half of the bits will have changed state.

For example, change one bit of a file and the MD5 checksum of the file becomes completely different.

Is there any hash function/checksum that does not have the diffusion property? Ideally, if 20% of the plaintext changes then 20% of the ciphertext should change and if 80% of the plaintext changes then 80% of the ciphertext should change. This way, % change in the plaintext can be tracked via the ciphertext.

Comment: You start out talking about "hash functions" and "checksums", but then you veer over into "plaintext" and "ciphertext", which is a completely different concept. There are plenty of encryption schemes where flipping one bit of plaintext will flip one bit of ciphertext if you keep the nonce the same (which is why it's so important *not* to keep the nonce the same), but hash functions and checksums generally produce a very tiny output relative to the input, so they don't contain enough information for that to b possible.

Comment: I imagine such functions could exist (with caveats, at least), but they may not be well-researched, because they aren't as useful to cryptography. You might want to ask this question on [Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/), but they might expect the question to be more precise, as ruakh mentioned.

Comment: Sounds like you're describing the identity function.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest thing to what you appear to be looking for is "locality sensitive hashing", which attempts to map similar inputs to similar outputs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing

The amount of change in the hash is not really proportional to the amount of change in the input, but maybe it'll do for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the purpose of your hash-function is, you might not need the diffusion property.

E.g for large data blobs you might want to avoid reading all bytes to generate a hash-value (because of performance). So using only the first 1000 Bytes to calculate a hash-value might be good enough for usage in a HashSet, if the 1000 bytes differ enough through your data sets.

---

**Related to your % question:**

You can create such a function, but that is quite an unusual extra feature of the hash-function.

E.g. You can split your data in 100 equal sized chunks calculate the md5 for each of them and than take the first n bytes of each md5-value and append them to create your hash-value. this way you can determine the % value out of the of the fact how many n-bytes blocks changed in your hash-value (you can even see at which position your data changed)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these functions do exist and are called **very bad** hash functions.
People come up with such nonsense from time to time.
The diffusion property is an essential property of a good hash function.

E.g. you could return the **address** of the string which does look like a real hash function looking from outside, but when you change the string in place without reallocation, you see no diffusion, no change.

Or language implementors **cut off** long strings during faster hash processing. These hashes will collide when you change characters at the end of the string. If you are happy with bad hashes and many collisions it's still a valid hash function. This is done in practice. Your miles may vary.